# Do Until loop not working. Any ideas?

Tags: excel, vba, nested-loops

I am trying to make a program which moves ranges of cells, but one of my Do loops isn't working. In particular elements of the column crawling. When the program is run only A7:A9 get filled instead of A7:J9. The crawling does work for the movement of line 1 to L1 and works if there is no value in the red line (if A10 is blank then B7:B9 will fill). What is my mistake?

```
Sub Columntest()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    i = 1
    j = 2
    k = 7
    Do Until i = 11
        Range("L1").Formula = Cells(1, i)
        If Cells(10, i).Value = "Low" Then
            Do Until j = 6
                Cells(j + 15, 1).Formula = Cells(j, i)
            j = j + 1
            Loop
                Do Until k = 10
                    Cells(k + 5, 1).Copy
                    Cells(k, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                k = k + 1
                Loop
        End If
        If Cells(10, i).Value = "High" Then
            Do Until j = 6
                Cells(j + 15, 1).Formula = Cells(j, i)
            j = j + 1
            Loop
                Do Until k = 10
                    Cells(k + 5, 2).Copy
                    Cells(k, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                k = k + 1
                    Loop
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: Have you walked through it to see where it goes awry?

Comment: If either the k or j loops are left in then it does not move on to the second column etc. The issue seems to be with the Do Loop thinking it is complete after ending the If function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J & K Variable should be set to default inside do while loop:

```
i = 1

Do Until i = 11

    j = 2
    k = 7
    ......
    ......
    ...... and so son
```

Because once the J & K reaches to max values after the first loop, it will never enter in the Do While Loop of J & K again until you reset the J & K's values.

Comment: Thank you. This now works perfectly, I'd vote up but I haven't the reputation yet.

Comment: It's ok. Glad I could help. Thanks,V